# Use ng-file-upload like a normal file type form input

Tags: ng-file-upload

Mu current form works with an usual form file input :

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
</form>
```

Is it possible to use the `ng-file-upload` directive to replace the input to make use of its `ngf-drop` and `ngf-select` (to simply display file info easily for example) as well as style it easily, without using it with AJAX ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just use `ngf-select ng-model="files"` to display files info. If you use input type file the same element will be used so styles would be the same as normal input. For ngf-drop you need to have a div or similar element. There are jsfiddle samples on the docs.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very clear, the result I want is a div that works like a normal input (form input wise), but has the style of a div and its functionalities through `ngf-select` and `ngf-drop`

Comment: You cannot drop a file into an input type file and for the security you cannot set the value of the input type file programmatically so the only way for drop to work that i could think of is an ajax request.